# SQL 2005 stored procedure to return value or create it if it does not exist

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am having trouble with a stored procedure (SQL 2005).

I have a table called `tbrm_Tags` with two columns, `TagID` and `TagName`. I want to pass a `TagName` value to the stored procedure and then I want to:

1. Check if the `Tagname` exists and if it does return the `TagID`
2. If the `Tagname` does not exist I want it to insert into the table and return the `TagID`.

Here is the stored procedure I am using:

```
  @TagID int = null,
  @TagName varchar(50)  

AS

DECLARE @returnValue int

  BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbrm_Tags WHERE TagName = @TagName)
  BEGIN

  SELECT

  TagID

  FROM tbrm_Tags

  WHERE TagName = @TagName

END
ELSE
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbrm_Tags WHERE TagName = @TagName)

   INSERT INTO tbrm_Tags

  (
    TagName

  )
  VALUES
  (
    @TagName

      )

  SELECT @returnValue = @@IDENTITY

  END
  END

  RETURN @returnValue
```

I cannot get the select statement to return the `TagID` when the `Tagname` exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note: don't use `@@IDENTITY` - it is subject to triggers; always use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

I might just do:

```
DECLARE @returnValue int

SELECT @returnValue = TagID
FROM tbrm_Tags
WHERE TagName = @TagName

IF @returnValue IS NULL
BEGIN
     INSERT tbrm_Tags(TagName)
     VALUES (@TagName)

     SET @returnValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END

RETURN @returnValue
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT

@returnValue = TagID

FROM tbrm_Tags

WHERE TagName = @TagName
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Marc G.'s code would work just fine, but I would have made the last line like this:

```
SELECT @returnValue AS RETURNVALUE
```

I've always done it that way, but I am not sure of there is any functional difference between the two methods...anyone know?

Comment: There is a huge difference. One uses the return-value of the proc; the other returns a grid with one cell. The two are incompatible. The return-value is a bit (not massively) more efficient, and a lot cleaner if you are calling from TSQL directly (INSERT/EXEC is a mess).